# Limit of the following trig function

Tags: calculus

I am struggling a lot with finding the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\sin x}}{x^3}$$

Can anyone please help me? You can use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: multiply the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{1 + tg(x)} + \sqrt{1 + sin(x)}$

Comment: I have rearranged your question and suppressed the big image (no need to take a photograph of the whole page !) ; please, learn the basics of latex for your next question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\sin x}}{x^3}=\dfrac{1+\tan x-(1+\sin x)}{x^3}\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}}$$

Now $$\dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}=\dfrac1{\cos x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}x\cdot\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$$

$$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2\cdot\dfrac1{1+\cos x}$$

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Remove the difference of square roots by the usual trick
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\sin x}}{x^3}=\frac{(\not1+\tan x)-(\not1+\sin x)}{x^3\bigl(\sqrt{1+\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}\bigr)}$$
and use Maclaurin's expansions of $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ at order $3$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we haven't yet talked about Taylor series, but I will look it up!

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\sin x}}{x^3}= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ (1+\frac{1}{2}\tan x)-(1+\frac{1}{2}\sin x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2} \frac{(x+x^3/3+o(x^5)-(x-x^3/6+o(x^5))}{x^3}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: For the sake of rigour, you should add $o(x^3)$ to both expansions.